# Nodemailer is not working when another user is sending

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Nodemailer is working for me. I can send emails. I deployed my application to heroku and I can still send emails. But when another user or another pc or connection is using the application, the app is not sending emails anymore. But when I do. It is still sending emails. I don't know how to fix this. I'm using Nodemailer(gmail, xoauth2)

Comment: Do I need to enable the gmail_api in every account of the user who will send emails? :(

Comment: By another user do you mean, their Gmail(or any email server) credentials are used in nodemailer to send emails? Or does it mean that they are using the API that you have deployed on Heroku?

Comment: i mean, they are using the application i deployed in heroku but when they send an email. for example they send an email to me using the app. Im not receiving any emails. And I tried using firefox and use the application and send an email to my gmail account. I didn't receive any emails.

Comment: It's working in firefox now. Maybe I can hope that it is working smoothly now because of "allow less secure apps: on" on my gmail. But is there any other way to override the 'from' when sending email? because it still shows the user gmail that I am using.

Comment: Overriding from means you'll also need credentials of user, which I believe anyone would be hesitant to provide.

Comment: What I mean is change the from. like instead of showing the actual gmail account then it will show ex: noreply@gmail.com

Comment: Oh, nodemailer does not provide such functionality. What we do is that we create an id which goes by name of noreply.xyz@mail.com. But I would like to know if you find some alternative to it. :)